# Force Yesod to use newer version of Warp

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack, haskell-warp

I installed Yesod using Stack. It currently uses Warp v3.2.11.1, but I want it to use [the latest version available on GitHub](https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/tree/master/warp) (it hasn't been released yet). I added the following to my `stack.yaml` file:

```yaml
packages:
- '.'
- location:
    git: git@github.com:yesodweb/wai.git
    commit: 9fd0dcf221e4946d3588eea3ccd87492ca718d6a
  extra-dep: true
  subdirs:
    - warp
```

When I import Warp in `Application.hs` and print the Warp version, I get 3.2.11.2, but when I make HTTP requests to my server, the "Server" response header is "Warp/3.2.11.1", which means that Yesod is still using the old version of Warp. How can I force Yesod to use the newer version?

Comment: Are you sure that header has been updated in the github version?

Comment: @Carl I think it displays the version from the `.cabal` file, and the version has been updated there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using `stack exec -- yesod devel` to run my server, and apparently this was causing the problem. When I run the executable built by stack, it works fine.